# How to delete matching brackets in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know you can jump between matching brackets with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>. I would like to place the cursor right after a bracket and delete both that bracket and its matching one as easily as possible.

Since with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click you can have multiple selections, I was looking for something similar to: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> for placing another cursor on the matching bracket and then deleting both with a single backspace.

Is there any shortcut deleting a pair of matching brackets/parenthesis?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the v1.77 Insiders Build now (and probably in Stable v1.77 early April 2023) is a new command:

```
Remove Brackets
editor.action.removeBrackets
```

By default bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on Mac.

This command will remove matching brackets that surround the cursor position.  So the cursor can be anywhere - it doesn't have to be right next to one of the brackets - in code or text that has a surrounding bracket.  (It doesn't appear to reformat after the bracket deletions though).

Comment: This should be the top answer now that it works

Comment: In some linux distro `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Baksoace` restarts the machine

Comment: Works for me on 1.79, with the shortcut on Mac being `Cmd` + `Opt` + `Backspace`.

Comment: WARNING!
this shortcut probably SHUT DOWN YOUR X11 system on linux !!!

Answer (score 44):

There is an extension called [Bracketeer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pustelto.bracketeer) that does what you want.

First, install with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>, then `ext install pustelto.bracketeer`, followed by an enter.

You can then add the following to your `keybindings.json`

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+backspace",
    "command": "bracketeer.removeBrackets"
  },
```

You can then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> to remove matching brackets.

Comment: Is there a way to also delete the lines that have the brackets, and de-indent the code in between all in one swift keystroke?

Comment: @mrvladimir Have you discovered a way to also delete the lines of these brackets? Reindenting could happen with auto format on save using a formatter like `prettier`.

Comment: @alexanderdavide No, unfortunately I have not.

Comment: Is there something like this published on Open VSX? I'm using Codium.

Comment: You don't need an extension for that anymore, see the other answer.

Answer (score -5):

This works for (), {} and []

```
Sub DeleteMatchingBrace()
Dim sel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
Dim ap As VirtualPoint = sel.ActivePoint

If (sel.Text() <> "") Then Exit Sub
' reposition
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToBrace") : DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToBrace") 

If (ap.DisplayColumn <= ap.LineLength) Then sel.CharRight(True)

Dim c As String = sel.Text
Dim isRight As Boolean = False
If (c <> "(" And c <> "[" And c <> "{") Then
    sel.CharLeft(True, 1 + IIf(c = "", 0, 1))
    c = sel.Text
    sel.CharRight()
    If (c <> ")" And c <> "]" And c <> "}") Then Exit Sub
    isRight = True
End If

Dim line = ap.Line
Dim pos = ap.DisplayColumn
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToBrace")
If (isRight) Then sel.CharRight(True) Else sel.CharLeft(True)

sel.Text = ""
If (isRight And line = ap.Line) Then pos = pos - 1
sel.MoveToDisplayColumn(line, pos)
sel.CharLeft(True)
sel.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Then add a shortcut to this macro in VS

Comment: How do I add this to VS Code?

Comment: If you want you can create a class specifically for that or a method.

Comment: But that language is Visual Basic, right? Note that I want it to work in Visual Studio Code, not in Visual Studio, perhaps you are thinking about the latter (if not, I'm completely lost).

Comment: Visual Studio Code <> Visual Studio.